# array length changes in openjdk

Tags: arrays, linux, java

I've recently seen strange behaviour in my application that I can't really explain.  They occur very unfrequent so I can't reproduce them.  While the place where these problems occur changes, the common part seems to be that an array changes size after it has been created (I know, this is not possible, hence: strange behaviour).

A couple of examples to make my point clear:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 86
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:409)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:577)
    at com.acunia.fleet.diagnostics.providers.tacho.VDOKLineInputParser.getRealDriverID(Unknown Source)
```

The code that would cause this:

```
public String getRealDriverID(byte[] buffer) {
  if (buffer.length > 86 && isDriverCardInserted(buffer)) {
    return new String(buffer, 70, 16);
  }   
  return null;
}
```

So we first check that the buffer is big enough (more than 86 bytes) before trying to create a String from them.

A second example:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(String.java:1889)
    at java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(String.java:1835)
    at java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(String.java:1817)
    at com.acunia.service.position.nmea.comm.CommPositionProvider.isValid(Unknown Source)
```

The line that causes this exception is:

```
int csi = line.lastIndexOf("*");
```

I had a look at the openjdk String.java source, but couldn't find a fault unless arrays could suddenly start changing size after they where created.

The only reference online that I could find that might be related was as a openjdk bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6817012.  This bug was marked a 'not an issue' though, although when reading this I can't really tell if the problem that is mentioned is not recognized as a bug, or if the person who closed the bug doesn't see why this bug would cause problems.

If anyone has ever encountered a similar problem I would really appreciate hearing about it.  As it stands the problem is too unstable to attempt to fix it by using other versions of openjdk.

Problem was seen on:

```
hardware: custom arm platform
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
Linux 3.2.0 #1 Fri Jun 20 10:25:16 CEST 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You are using Java 6. Java 7 just reached end of life. You should really upgrade your Java.

Comment: The second example would be easily explained if the character does not appear in the String. In that case, lastIndexOf returns -1, and the complaint is about using index -1.

Comment: I'd also recomend upgrading your Java to 8 if possible. And preferrably the Oracle version. OpenJDK has given me nothing but headaches.

Comment: The application runs on embedded devices spread all over Europe (in moving vehicles).  While updating these is possible, it will be costly.  Furthermore I feel uncomfortable upgrading without some clear indication that the problem is no longer present in more recent java versions.

Comment: lastIndexOf should return -1 if the character does not appear, it should not however throw a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Considering you're using an fairly ancient JRE it's really hard to diagnose this problem without further details (what was the input? what was the system default charsete?). If you've ruled out the invalid charset explanation yourself, then it's pretty much impossible to give a clear answer to the question in it's current shape.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely an issue with the bytes and the system charset. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) explicitly says:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is **unspecified**.

You can circumvent this by explicitly providing the correct charset:

```
new String(buffer, 70, 16, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: (For UTF-8 use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead, then you do not need to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException` as the standard Charsets always are distributed with the JRE.)

Comment: Nice. Wasn't aware of that class. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: I read the source of the String class and it definitely has nothing to do with charsets, (checkBounds is called before attempting to convert the bytes to chars).

Comment: Given invalid bytes, the constructor is undefined, which may very well mean "return a broken String object that isn't aware of it's own bounds". Long story short: Either it's an issue with incompatibility between system default charset and input bytes, or there's an obscure bug in the JVM or String implementation of a now ancient (1.6) JRE. In the former case, there's a reasonable explanation, in the latter case it's virtually impossible to answer the question in it's current form.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the new `String` using `byte[]` array without specifying the `Charset`. Thus my guess is that system default charset got changed and you see the behaviour changes. I'd suggest to always specify the charset explicitly. For example:

```
return new String(buffer, 70, 16, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: We looked into that possibility.  The system is mostly read-only, so the default character set can't have been changed.  Furthermore if it would have been changed then the problem would have been seen in a lot of places, we saw only one occurrence of such an exception during the entire run.  Lastly, the checkBounds method in java.lang.String seems to check solely based on the size of the byte array, it doesn't take charset into account.

Comment: The charset may not have changed, but perhaps the input to the system that triggered this didn't occur very often?

Comment: The input is triggered roughly 4 times a second for this particular thread.  Other threads are triggered even more frequent.